# Bad Operando Types for binary operator " +" al querer sumar 2 variables tipo objeto

Tags: java, class, parámetros

Mi problema está en que  al querer usar el método `sumarRacionales()`, me aparece un globo de texto de error diciendo

[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Estoy llamando bien a los métodos de la clase `NumerosRacionales`?
¿Cómo podría hacerle para que me permita sumar numerador y denomindaro?

```java
public class Calculadora {
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        public Calculadora(){
        numerador = new NumerosRacionales();
        denominador = new NumerosRacionales();
        } // Se crea numerador/denominador, en los atributos se declara.
        
        // ATRIBUTOS
        private float resultado;
        private NumerosRacionales numerador;
        private NumerosRacionales denominador;
        
        // MÉTODOS
        public void sumarRacionales(){
            resultado=numerador+denominador;
        }
        
        public void setNumeradorDenominador(int newNumerador, int newDenominador){
            numerador.setNumerador(newNumerador);
            denominador.setDenominador(newDenominador);
        }
}
```

Comment: No puedes sumar instancias de clases, estas no son números. Tu código debería ser algo así `resultado = numerador.getNumerador() + denominador.getDenominador();`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, era lo que me hacía falta

Comment: Una pregunta, en caso de que quisiera guardar el valor de una instancia de clase en un entero, cómo le haría?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que obtienes:

> bad operand types for binary operator +

se debe a que tratas de sumar 2 tipos con el operador + el cual no es soportado para estos tipos.

El error al parecer lo tienes aquì:

```
    public void sumarRacionales(){
         resultado=numerador+denominador;
    }
```

Al ver los setter de tu còdigo, imagino que podrìas usar los getter para obtener el valor numerico y de esta forma si podrìas realizar la suma:

```
 public void sumarRacionales(){
      resultado = numerador.getNumerador() + denominador.getDenominador();
 }
```

---

Veo que preguntas como guardar el valor de la instancia en un entero, simplemente usa los getter para obtener el valor numerico y almacenarlo en una variable de tipo `int`:

```
public class Calculadora {
              
        private int valorNumerador;
        private int valorDenominador;
        
       public Calculadora(){

        numerador = new NumerosRacionales();
        denominador = new NumerosRacionales();
 
       //Almacena valores numericos
        valorNumerador = numerador.getNumerador(); 
        valorDenominador = denominador.getDenominador();

       } 
       
      ...
      ...
      ...

}
```